# No podspec found for xyz module

Tags: ios, swift, github, cocoapods, podfile

Hey I am trying to fetch **.podspec** file in my podfile. But I am getting weried issue

```
[!] No podspec found for `kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule` in `https://github.com/vivek-modi/MultiplatformProject/tree/master/app/kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule`
```

My project [link](https://github.com/vivek-modi/MultiplatformProject) and my [.podspec](https://github.com/vivek-modi/MultiplatformProject/tree/master/app/kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule) file are store in this location.

**podfile**

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

source 'https://github.com/vivek-modi/MultiplatformProject.git'

target 'PodIosProject' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for PodIosProject
  pod 'kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule', :path => "https://github.com/vivek-modi/MultiplatformProject/tree/master/app/kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule"

  target 'PodIosProjectTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'PodIosProjectUITests' do
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Can someone suggest me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `:path` is for local, not remote...

Comment: @Larme so what can I do instead ?

Comment: See https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html